# Consul agent on kubernetes, on node or pod?

Tags: kubernetes, consul

I deployed an aws eks cluster via terraform. I also deployed Consul following hasicorp’s tutorial and I see the nodes in consul’s UI.

Now I’m wondering how al the consul agents will know about the pods I deploy? I deploy something and it’s not shown anywhere on consul.

I can’t find any documentation as to how to register pods (services) on consul via the node’s consul agent, do I need to configure that somewhere? Should I not use the node’s agent and register the service straight from the pod? Hashicorp discourages this since it may increase resource utilization depending on how many pods one deploy on a given node. But then how does the node’s agent know about my services deployed on that node?

Moreover, when I deploy a pod in a node and ssh into the node, and install consul, consul’s agent can’t find the consul server (as opposed from the node, which can find it)

EDIT:

Bottom line is I can't find WHERE to add the configuration. If I execute ON THE POD:

`consul members`

It works properly and I get:

```
Node                          Address            Status  Type    Build   Protocol  DC         Segment
consul-consul-server-0        10.0.103.23:8301   alive   server  1.10.0  2         full  <all>
consul-consul-server-1        10.0.101.151:8301  alive   server  1.10.0  2         full  <all>
consul-consul-server-2        10.0.102.112:8301  alive   server  1.10.0  2         full  <all>
ip-10-0-101-129.ec2.internal  10.0.101.70:8301   alive   client  1.10.0  2         full  <default>
ip-10-0-102-175.ec2.internal  10.0.102.244:8301  alive   client  1.10.0  2         full  <default>
ip-10-0-103-240.ec2.internal  10.0.103.245:8301  alive   client  1.10.0  2         full  <default>
ip-10-0-3-223.ec2.internal    10.0.3.249:8301    alive   client  1.10.0  2         full  <default>
```

But if i execute:

```
# consul agent -datacenter=voip-full -config-dir=/etc/consul.d/ -log-file=log-file -advertise=$(wget -q -O - http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/local-ipv4)
```

I get the following error:

```
==> Starting Consul agent...
           Version: '1.10.1'
           Node ID: 'f10070e7-9910-06c7-0e12-6edb6cc4c9b9'
         Node name: 'ip-10-0-3-223.ec2.internal'
        Datacenter: 'voip-full' (Segment: '')
            Server: false (Bootstrap: false)
       Client Addr: [127.0.0.1] (HTTP: 8500, HTTPS: -1, gRPC: -1, DNS: 8600)
      Cluster Addr: 10.0.3.223 (LAN: 8301, WAN: 8302)
           Encrypt: Gossip: false, TLS-Outgoing: false, TLS-Incoming: false, Auto-Encrypt-TLS: false

==> Log data will now stream in as it occurs:

2021-08-16T18:23:06.936Z [WARN]  agent: skipping file /etc/consul.d/consul.env, extension must be .hcl or .json, or config format must be set
2021-08-16T18:23:06.936Z [WARN]  agent: Node name "ip-10-0-3-223.ec2.internal" will not be discoverable via DNS due to invalid characters. Valid characters include all alpha-numerics and dashes.
2021-08-16T18:23:06.946Z [WARN]  agent.auto_config: skipping file /etc/consul.d/consul.env, extension must be .hcl or .json, or config format must be set
2021-08-16T18:23:06.947Z [WARN]  agent.auto_config: Node name "ip-10-0-3-223.ec2.internal" will not be discoverable via DNS due to invalid characters. Valid characters include all alpha-numerics and dashes.
2021-08-16T18:23:06.948Z [INFO]  agent.client.serf.lan: serf: EventMemberJoin: ip-10-0-3-223.ec2.internal 10.0.3.223
2021-08-16T18:23:06.948Z [INFO]  agent.router: Initializing LAN area manager
2021-08-16T18:23:06.950Z [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=127.0.0.1:8600 network=udp
2021-08-16T18:23:06.950Z [WARN]  agent.client.serf.lan: serf: Failed to re-join any previously known node
2021-08-16T18:23:06.950Z [INFO]  agent: Started DNS server: address=127.0.0.1:8600 network=tcp
2021-08-16T18:23:06.951Z [INFO]  agent: Starting server: address=127.0.0.1:8500 network=tcp protocol=http
2021-08-16T18:23:06.951Z [WARN]  agent: DEPRECATED Backwards compatibility with pre-1.9 metrics enabled. These metrics will be removed in a future version of Consul. Set `telemetry { disable_compat_1.9 = true }` to disable them.
2021-08-16T18:23:06.953Z [INFO]  agent: started state syncer
2021-08-16T18:23:06.953Z [INFO]  agent: Consul agent running!
2021-08-16T18:23:06.953Z [WARN]  agent.router.manager: No servers available
2021-08-16T18:23:06.954Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No known Consul servers"
2021-08-16T18:23:34.169Z [WARN]  agent.router.manager: No servers available
2021-08-16T18:23:34.169Z [ERROR] agent.anti_entropy: failed to sync remote state: error="No known Consul servers"
```

So where to add the config?

I also tried adding a service in k8s pointing to the pod, but the service doesn't come up on consul's UI...

What do you guys recommend?

Thanks

Comment: Do you need consul when you use Kubernetes with its own etcd and "service registry"?

Comment: No, I’m planning to use consul for both service discovery and configuration management via k/v

Answer (score 2):

> Consul knows where these services are located because each service
> registers with its local Consul client. Operators can register
> services manually, configuration management tools can register
> services when they are deployed, or container orchestration platforms
> can register services automatically via integrations.

if you planning to use manual option you have to register the service into the consul.

Something like

```
echo '{
  "service": {
    "name": "web",
    "tags": [
      "rails"
    ],
    "port": 80
  }
}' > ./consul.d/web.json
```

You can find the good example at : https://thenewstack.io/implementing-service-discovery-of-microservices-with-consul/

Also this is a very nice document for having detailed configuration of the health check and service discovery : https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/multi/multi_spring-cloud-consul-discovery.html

Official document : https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/consul/get-started-service-discovery

Comment: Thanks. I’ve done that Register a Service tutorial, it’s good. What I don’t yet understand is how does the NODE agent know about any service I deploy in it? If I deploy a pod, the agent doesn’t seem to know about it, so I guess I’m missing some configuration to make the agent aware of it?

Comment: people use https://github.com/gliderlabs/registrator also for auto registering the services, if you don want to use it you can use the API of consul also to register service.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, I was finally able to figure out the issue.

consul-dns is not deployed by default, i had to manually deploy it, then forward all `.consul` requests from coredns to consul-dns.

All is working now. Thanks!